# How to tell if a key is held down

Tags: keyboard

How can i tell if a key is being held down as though it were part of a key combination like *Ctrl-Alt-Del* or *Alt-Tab*?

How does one go about accomplishing this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there are dozen of combinations of OS'es, toolkits, programming languages, keyboard layouts, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us more? What's the desired programming language and operating system?

In C#, VB or C++ on Windows you can use GetKeyState() and GetAsyncKeyState() to determine wether a key is (was) pressed and wether the key is up or down. ([MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx))

Comment: This would be in C and I want it to be portable, so using something Unique to windows is a no go.